# Method namespace clashing when running rake tasks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Using Rails 2.3.10
If my lib/tasks looks like this

```
lib/tasks
- a.rake
- b.rake
```

a.rake looks like this:

```
namespace :a do
    desc "Task A"
    task(:a=>:environment)do
      msg('I AM TASK A')
    end

    def msg(msg)
      puts "MSG SENT FROM Task A: #{msg}"
    end
end
```

b.rake looks like this

```
namespace :b do
    desc "Task B"
    task(:b=>:environment)do
      msg('I AM TASK B')
    end

    def msg(msg)
      puts "MSG SENT FROM Task B: #{msg}"
    end
end
```

Then when I run task a

```
rake a RAILS_ENV=sandbox
```

The output is
"MSG SENT FROM Task B: I AM TASK A"

So the msg() helper method defined in a.rake does not get called. Rather that defined in b.rake gets called. (What's more, if I have a c.rake - then *it's* msg helper method gets called when I run task a.

Is this method namespace clashing known behavior?
I would have thought the namespacing would have prevented this.

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

What you observe is that **methods in rake files namespaces redefine** previously defined methods with the same name. The reason for this is that Rake `namespace`s are very different than Ruby namespaces (classes or modules), in fact they only serve as a **namespace for the names of the tasks defined in them**, *but nothing else*. Thus, task `a` becomes task `a:a` if placed in the `a` namespace but other code outside the tasks shares the *same* global namespace.

This fact, together with the fact that **Rake loads all tasks** before running the given task, explains why the method gets redefined.

#### TL;DR: Solutions / hints for the name clashes

You cannot expect that two methods with the same name (or any other code) placed inside separate `namespace`s but outside tasks will work properly. Nevertheless, here are a couple of hints to solve such situation:

- Place the methods **inside the tasks**. If both `msg` methods were defined inside the `a:a` and `b:b` tasks, then both rake tasks would run properly and would display the expected messages.
- If you need to use the code from the rake's `namespace` in multiple rake tasks, **extract the methods / code to a real Ruby namespace**, such as two modules, and `include` the code in the tasks that need it. Consider this rewrite of the sample rakes:

  ```
  # lib/tasks/a.rake:
  module HelperMethodsA
    def msg(msg)
      puts "MSG SENT FROM Task A: #{msg}"
    end
  end

  namespace :a do
    desc "Task A"
    task(:a => :environment) do
      include HelperMethodsA
      msg('I AM TASK A')
    end
  end

  # lib/tasks/b.rake:
  module HelperMethodsB
    def msg(msg)
      puts "MSG SENT FROM Task B: #{msg}"
    end
  end

  namespace :b do
    desc "Task B"
    task(:b => :environment) do
      include HelperMethodsB
      msg('I AM TASK B')
    end
  end
  ```

  Because the two modules have different names and because they are `include`d in the respective tasks, both rake tasks will again run as expected.

*Now, let's prove the above claims with the help of the source code...*

#### Proof that Rake loads all tasks first and why it does so

This one's easy. In the main `Rakefile` you'll always find the following line:

```
Rails.application.load_tasks
```

This method eventually calls the following code from the Rails engine:

```
def run_tasks_blocks(*) #:nodoc:
  super
  paths["lib/tasks"].existent.sort.each { |ext| load(ext) }
end
```

Thus, it searches the `lib/tasks` directories for all rake files and loads them one after each other, in a sorted order. That's why the `b.rake` file will be loaded after `a.rake` and whatever is inside it will potentially redefine the code from `a.rake` and all previously loaded rake files.

Rake has to load all rake files simply because the rake `namespace` names do not have to be the same as rake filenames, so the rake filename cannot be inferred from the  task / namespace name.

#### Proof that rake's `namespace`s don't constitute a real Ruby-like namespace

Upon loading the rake files, the Rake DSL statements get executed, and also the `namespace` method. The method takes the block of code defined inside it and executes it (using `yield`) **in the context of the `Rake.application` object** which is a singleton object of the `Rake::Application` class that is shared among all rake tasks. There is no dynamic module / class created for the namespace, it's just executed in the main object context.

```
# this reuses the shared Rake.application object and executes the namespace code inside it
def namespace(name=nil, &block)
  # ...
  Rake.application.in_namespace(name, &block)
end

# the namespace block is yielded in the context of Rake.application shared object
def in_namespace(name)
  # ...
  @scope = Scope.new(name, @scope)
  ns = NameSpace.new(self, @scope)
  yield(ns)
  # ...
end
```

See the relevant sources [here](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb#L134) and [here](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/task_manager.rb#L214).

#### Rake tasks DO constitute ruby namespaces

With Rake tasks themselves, the situation is different, though. For each task, **a separate object** of the `Rake::Task` class (or of a similar class) is created and the task code is run inside this object's context. The creation of the object is done in the [`intern` method](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/task_manager.rb#L61) in the task manager:

```
def intern(task_class, task_name)
  @tasks[task_name.to_s] ||= task_class.new(task_name, self)
end
```

#### A quote form the Rake's author

Finally, all this is confirmed by this [interesting discussion on github](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/issues/186) that deals with a very similar and related issue, and from which we can quote Jim Weirich, the original author of Rake:

> Since namespaces don't introduce real method scopes, the only real possibility for a scope is the DSL module.
>
> ...
>
> Perhaps, someday, the Rake namespaces will become full class scoped entities with a place to hang lazy let definitions, but we are not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use namespace like the following:

```
namespace :rake_a do
  desc "Task A"
  task(:a=>:environment)do
    msg('I AM TASK A')
  end

  def msg(msg)
    puts "MSG SENT FROM Task A: #{msg}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been doing - although my code snippets don't show it (I'll update them). The rake namespacing has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The rake namespace is only intended for rake tasks.
See the Rake documentations:
`The NameSpace class will lookup task names in the the scope defined by a namespace command.`

You can create a module along with your rake namespace to cover this problem:

```
module A do

    module_functions

    def msg(msg)
      puts "MSG SENT FROM Task A: #{msg}"
    end
end

namespace :a do
    desc "Task A"
    task(:a=>:environment)do
       A.msg('I AM TASK A')
    end
end
```